# How can I paste multi-rows from Excel to a DataGridView in C#?

Tags: c#

I am trying to paste rows from an Excel sheet to a `DataGridView` in C#.
I have used the following code:

```
private void PasteClipboard(DataGridView myDataGridView)
    {
        DataObject o = (DataObject)Clipboard.GetDataObject();
        if (o.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
        {
            if (myDataGridView.RowCount > 0)
                myDataGridView.Rows.Clear();

            if (myDataGridView.ColumnCount > 0)
                myDataGridView.Columns.Clear();

            bool columnsAdded = false;
            string[] pastedRows = Regex.Split(o.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString().TrimEnd("\r\n".ToCharArray()), "\r\n");
            foreach (string pastedRow in pastedRows)
            {
                string[] pastedRowCells = pastedRow.Split(new char[] { '\t' });

                if (!columnsAdded)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < pastedRowCells.Length; i++)
                        myDataGridView.Columns.Add("col" + i, pastedRowCells[i]);

                    columnsAdded = true;
                    continue;
                }

                myDataGridView.Rows.Add();
                int myRowIndex = myDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1;

                using (DataGridViewRow myDataGridViewRow = myDataGridView.Rows[myRowIndex])
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < pastedRowCells.Length; i++)
                        myDataGridViewRow.Cells[i].Value = pastedRowCells[i];
                }
            }
```

[image]

However, as a result, only one row contains data while the others are empty. For instance, if I copy and paste 3 rows, the 3rd row is the only row with data and the other two rows are empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you convert the Clibboard data into a DataTable and then use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
int myRowIndex = myDataGridView.Rows.Add();
```

Instead of this:

```
myDataGridView.Rows.Add();
int myRowIndex = myDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1;
```

Note that when you create a new row, you also receive the index of that row, as the return value of `myDataGridView.Rows.Add();` . Your code ignores that value and instead it assumes that the newly created row will always be the last one: `myDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1;`

Comment: so do you mean that i have to replace myDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1; by myDataGridView.Rows.Add(); ?

Comment: Yes you need to replace that line as mentioned by @Andy.

Comment: Yes, you are right. thank you both  @Andy and @M Adeel Khalid